# Uninstall Postgresql in silent mode

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-10

I lookup a lot to find a solution to uninstall postgresql in silent mode without using GUI. Something like unattended mode in installation.
Even when I try to uninstall from uninstall.exe it run GUI.
So, is it possible to uninstall postgresql in silent mode or even without uninstall GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can uninstall postgresql in silent mode using "--mode unattended". 
`uninstall-postgresql.exe --mode unattended`